# unable to create Maven project in eclipse(Luna)

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to create Maven project in eclipse(Luna) but I am getting error while creating project.Can anyone tell me how to create maven project in Eclipse(Luna).

[image]

In workspace->.metadata->.log file

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2015-07-07 11:17:28.424
!MESSAGE Unable to create project from archetype [co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2 -> http://maven-repository.com/artifact/co.ntier/spring-mvc-archetype/1.0.2]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.core 4 -1 2015-07-07 11:17:28.427
!MESSAGE Unable to create project from archetype [co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2 -> http://maven-repository.com/artifact/co.ntier/spring-mvc-archetype/1.0.2]
!STACK 0
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: The defined artifact is not an archetype
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetype.generateProjectFromArchetype(DefaultArchetype.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenProjectWizard.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: i am also facing the same error can any one help to fix this

Comment: Could you give us the error in logs located in workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: @NelsonG. how can I send the log file because its exceeding the characters in comment box

Comment: Reproduce the error and copy only last lines in the file or only the line with the error.

Comment: @NelsonG. check my edited question with log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems eclipse fail to generate this artifact because given parameters are wrong. Try to create it with command line then import it into eclipse as a maven project :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeGroupId=co.ntier -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: eventhough it showing this error, Command line option 'D' [from -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app] is not known.

Comment: can u help me to overcome from this

Comment: linux ubuntu and my command sudo apt-get install mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeGroupId=co.ntier -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 -DinteractiveMode=false

Comment: Not 'sudo apt-get install mvn ...', only 'mvn ...', apt-get install is used to install linux packages

Comment: anand@anand-desktop:~$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeGroupId=co.ntier -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 -DinteractiveMode=false
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: Because maven is not installed ! Install it before (sudo apt-get install maven I think) then create your project with mvn archetype:generate ...

Comment: Okay Nelson Thak you soo much for ur valuable time

Comment: yea its working after i installed using this cmd(sudo apt-get install maven) and followed by this command 'mvn ...' it shows build failure

Comment: maven-archetype-plugin:2.3 and but if i use this mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong -DartifactId=CounterWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false  I got Build success.I don't know why??

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer didn't work. Try the following if you face the same issue.

**File -> New project -> Maven Project -> Next -> Click on Add Archetype**

Enter the following details

> **Archetype Group Id:** co.ntier
>
> **Archetype Artifact Id:** spring-mvc-archetype
>
> **Archetype Version:** 1.0.2
>
> **Repository URL:** http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

If it fails again, **delete everything inside .m2/repository** folder & try the above steps again.